# applying a timed hold after mouseover to a css hover element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this is probably very simple using javascript or jquery, but I cannot wrap my head around it.  I am providing a sample using a simple css box with a :hover applied in a different color.  I want the box to go about the hover as it normally would, but then want the hover to last a set amount of time, regardless of mouse movement after hover.  After the set time has finished, I would like the hover to reset as normal.  Also if the user were to accidentally hover over the #box  while the hover is being held it will not reset, it will continue to hold until after the set time has finished.

here is my html and css

```
    #box {
            width: 200px;
            height:300px;
            background-color: #00CCFF; 
    }

    #box:hover {
            width: 200px;
            height:300px;
            background-color: #669933;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="box" </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.box-normal {
        width: 200px;
        height:300px;
        background-color: #00CCFF; 
}

.box-hover {
        width: 200px;
        height:300px;
        background-color: #669933;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>   

   <div id="box" class="box-normal"> dsfdsf</div>

</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
var delayms = 2000;

$("#box").mouseenter(function(){
    if ($("#box").hasClass('box-normal'))
    {
         $("#box").removeClass('box-normal').addClass('box-hover');
         window.setTimeout(function() {
             $("#box").removeClass('box-hover').addClass('box-normal'); 
         }, delayms); 
    }     
}); 

});
```

You can change the "delayms" variable. ( 2000 means 2 seconds)

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqT7d/1/

Also [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) suggests a simpler version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jqT7d/3/

Comment: Why use `box-normal` and `box-hover`?  You can just have default CSS that is superceded by `box-hover` and only change one class instead of two.  It would simplify it.

Comment: I already posted a jsFiddle that illustrates it in my last comment.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your post with the better version so your answer is as good as you can make it.  Feel free to use the ideas we discussed here in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.navigator-wrap-inner li.thumbnail_resize:hover {
  border-color:#184ACD;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```